# Obtener el resto de 31 bits en C#

Tags: c#, números-enteros

En *C* puedo obtener el resto de dividir `x` por 2<sup>31</sup> al castear un `long` como entero:

```
printf("%i",(int)3000000000);
```

Como respuesta obtengo:

```
-1294967296
```

En *C#* intenté hacer el resto de esta manera, para sacar 2<sup>31</sup> multiplicar 1024, es decir, 2<sup>10</sup> tres veces para obtener 2<sup>30</sup> y luego multiplicar por 2:

```
var i = 3000000000;
Console.WriteLine(i%(1024*1024*1024*2));
```

Pero me salta el siguiente error:

> The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode

¿De qué manera puedo lograr esto en *C#*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer `var i`, se está haciendo una inferencia de *`int` sin signo* como `uint`, que es el tipo inferido del número *3000000000*.

- La inferencia de un `uint` es para un número mayor o igual a *2147483648* y menor o igual a  *4294967295*, es decir, entre *2<sup>31</sup>* y *2<sup>32</sup>-1*.
- La inferencia de un `long` es desde *4294967296* hasta [*9223372036854775807*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/9_223_372_036_854_775_807), que en potencias de 2, es desde *2<sup>32</sup>* hasta *2<sup>63</sup>-1*.

Se puede crear otra variable haciendo una *conversión implícita*, es decir, casteando (moldeando) la variable original de `uint` a `int`, entonces en este caso la variable queda como un `int`. A esta variable la podemos llamar `resto`

Por último se puede volver a castear el `resto` hacia `long`, que es un tipo de dato que soporta números más altos y además negativos, como lo es en este ejemplo, *-1294967296*.

Código:

```
var i = 3000000000; // Se declara un uint.
var resto = (long)(int)i; // Se castea a int pero queda un long.
Console.WriteLine(resto);
```

Salida:

```
-1294967296
```